# Multithreading in Python or Serial Processing?

Tags: python, c++, multithreading

In the book "Multithreading for Visual Effects" i read following lines:

> Anything running in Python is the only thing running in Python, This means that if your execution callbacks are all implemented in Python, you lose much of the efficiency gains of a multithreaded system.
>
> The Python interpreter is not threadsafe --  it cannot be run rom multiple threads simultaneously. A thread that needs to use Python must wait for its turn to use the interpreter.

Why is this statement True?

This is bound to the idea, that the code is executed from within C++.

```
static void MyCallback(const Context &context){
Auto<Lock> lock(GetMyMutexFromContext(context));
...
EvalMyPythonString(str); //A function that takes the GIL
...    
}
```

So what is exactly meant? Can we not start multiple interpreters?

Comment: Have a read of this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/186889/why-was-python-written-with-the-gil

Comment: Hmm, did i understand correctly, that this only applies when two processes want to interact with one python interpreter right?

Answer (score 0):

> Anything running in Python is the only thing running in Python, This means that if your execution callbacks are all implemented in Python, you lose much of the efficiency gains of a multithreaded system.
>
> The Python interpreter is not threadsafe -- it cannot be run rom multiple threads simultaneously. A thread that needs to use Python must wait for its turn to use the interpreter.

Is this statement true? It depends on which python interpreter you're using.

**With Cpython:** Because of Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), there is only one thread can run at the same time. So you cannot take the performance advantages of using multiple threads. Even, your program will slower when using multiple threads in Cpython.

If you want to write parallel programs in Cpython, you should use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.). Its interfaces is same as [threading](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html) module.

Or, you can use multiple threading in Jython, Ironthon.